# Getting 404-error in my first spring project?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I've just got into Spring MVC and I wanted to write my first spring controller to test the stuff that I learn on. I made something basic that just sends back a massage but when I click button in the web page to trigger the get request and implicitly the controller I get a 404 error. I've checked the spring reference and their examples but couldn't find any explanation why I am getting that error. So I've come here for some help. Here is my code:
  web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
        <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet- 
class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<context:component-scan base-package="Controllers"/>


</beans>
```

appliationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<context:component-scan base-package="Controllers"/>


</beans>
```

MainController:

```
package Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting.form")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, 
defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Adrian
  Date: 6/6/2018
  Time: 12:05 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting.form">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: Here is screenshot with the project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks0CH.jpg

Comment: You are using obsolete tutorials. Start with the Spring Boot Getting Started Guides, and I personally recommend using Thymeleaf instead of JSP, because JSP has serious limitations in modern applications.

Comment: @chrylis can you say more about the jsp limitations in modern applications? thank you

Comment: please add your project structure screenshot

Comment: @lucumt https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: I've added the screenshot

Comment: @chrylis I,ve used the Spring Documentation to learn Sprin Framework which included spring mvc as well,but I've used the doc. from an older version of Spring Framework because it was comprehensive

Comment: But I've checked now,the latest version is 5.1 and I've used the documentation from 4.3. Is it that obsolete?

Comment: Put jsp file inside WEB-INF .

Comment: If I do that, I get 404. I've added     ` <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>` but no use

Comment: @AdiPascu Spring 4.3 isn't obsolete, but using `web.xml` and other XML configuration is. Spring Boot makes all of that unnecessary.

Comment: I've figured it out. Apparently the dispatcher servlet can't use controllers that arent't explecetly declared as beans. As soon as I declared the controller as a bean everything worked. Thanks everyone for your help!